# Getting custom type from TempData asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, tempdata

I have a custom class MyCustomType. In that class I have a property MyCustomProperty of type bool and another property MyCustomProperty1 of type bool also.

I need to check if MyCustomProperty is true in my View. I`m doing the following thing:

```
<%if ( TempData[ViewDataConstants.MyCustomTypeKey] != null && ((MyCustomType)TempData[ViewDataConstants.MyCustomTypeKey]).MyCustomProperty %>show some custom content.
```

But for some reason when I`m running it I see error message that MyCustomTYpe could not be found are you missing an assembly reference bla-bla-bla. MyCustomType is in my controller it`s public and to check I even added a reference to the view. But it keep saying that there`s no MyCustomType class. What am I doing wrong?

Interesting, for some reason when I moved it to Common from Controllers namespace it suddenly worked. Still dont see why its not working while in Controllers namespace.
Both namespaces were included explicitly in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why it didn't work but quite honestly having all this code in a view looks wrong to me. Maybe it's just like me, Visual Studio doesn't like writing C# code in a view :-).

This should be a property on your view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public bool MyCustomProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and inside your controller:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var model = TempData[ViewDataConstants.MyCustomTypeKey] as MyCustomType ?? new MyCustomType();
    var viewModel = Mapper.Map<MyCustomType, MyViewModel>(model);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

and finally inside your view:

```
<% if (Model.MyCustomProperty) { %>
    show some custom content.
<% } %>
```

Now you no longer need any usings, castings, ... in the view.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Darin. I thought about this kind of approach, the what made me doubt is that my ViewModels are DTOs and they are only presenting what I should have in my View (not a good point to refuse it yet) and ViewData should be used in some way also. But in this scenario it seems you can use only model itself. 
Other way I was thinking of was to use ViewData.Model. What do you think about it?